# Ruby+Sinatra+nginx=403 Forbidden

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, passenger

I have install ruby+nginx server+sinatra, but currently I'm having error with 403 forbidden error. Log says:

```
2015/08/07 15:03:07 [error] 2902#0: *4 directory index of "/home/ruby-deployer/sin-app/hello/" is forbidden, client: ::1, server: 172.17.0.252, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", host: "localhost"
```

My virtual host config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name 172.17.0.252;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env    production;
    root          /home/ruby-deployer/sin-app/hello;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
```

}

nginx.conf:

```
 ##
    # Phusion Passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
    ##

    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    passenger_ruby /home/ruby-deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/wrappers/ruby;
```

hello/app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
'Hello world!'
end
```

hello/config.ru:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require './app.rb'
run Sinatra::Application
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd say this question should belong in serverfault

Comment: first in nginx add on the first line user your_username, if it doesn't work chmod the folder where your app sits

Comment: chmod 777 - It was the first thing, that I'm check

Answer (score 1):

Go to your nginx config file, and add `user your_user_name;` as a first line UPDATE: save and restart server.

If that doesn't work give more access to `/home/ruby-deployer/sin-app/hello` by using

```
chmod 755 /home/ruby-deployer/sin-app/hello
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it doesn't help :(

Comment: After restart I see the same picture: 403 Forbidden nginx/1.8.0

Comment: Try and chmod 755 home/ruby-deployer/sin-app if that is still not working try and chmod 755 home/ruby-deployer/